# When you auto-create subdomains on user signup does it create a new website or gives appearance of a website?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, user-accounts

I am wondering if subdomains that are created upon signup become websites or do they just give the illusion that they are websites sort of like example.com/username?

I am trying to create something like user.domain.com and can't really find something helpful to do it? Is there a way I do it so that i can allow customizations for the account for clients?

I need them to be like standalone websites so that i can go and customize them upon client requests, so what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have answered the main points of your question, but I did want to touch on what you call the "illusion" of a website.

There are a few different ways to serve a given application in a domain, subdomain or directory, from static files, to a single file handling every request no matter what path or domain was requested. No method is more or less "real" than any other. The only method I would call an "illusion" would be a website masked behind another website using frames, which is generally a Really Bad Idea. (Try bookmarking on a site where the URL doesn't change as you click around.)

Answer (score 4):

Subdomains usually map to a specific path on the webserver. For example, Apache specifies these paths in `httpd.conf`, they are called VirtualHost. An example may look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.domain.org
DocumentRoot "apache2/htdocs/domain/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This entry maps the Uri `subdomain.domain.org` to the path `apache2/htdocs/domain/`. Now, you can modify or present a page in that path, and it won't collide with other sites.

Comment: Also helpful: [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

Comment: Thanks Femearef.  This is definitely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite specific to where you're signing up.  There's no intrinsic connection between domains, subdomains, and hosting accounts -- you could have example.com hosted somewhere, and subdomain.example.com hosted somewhere totally different if you wanted.  It's all about your host, their setup, and how you/they set up DNS.

You could accomplish this somewhat easily by having two sites, one for example.com and one for *.example.com, and have the latter base the document root on the first part of the name.  In Apache, this is as simple as

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/site/subdomains/%1
```

As far as a browser would be concerned, each name represents a different site, and there'd be little or no leakage between sites if cookies are set up properly.  The only problem would be FTP access, if you decide to grant that -- each user would have to be set up to have their subdir as their home dir, and ideally chrooted or something so they couldn't go and look at other people's stuff.  Obviously, that will require some cooperation with/from your web host.  (At the very least, in order to use `VirtualDocumentRoot`, they'd need to have mod_vhost_alias running.  There are other ways involving mod_rewrite, but any way you do it is going to have the same issue with FTP access.)

Answer (score 2):

Your DNS record will need a wildcard for `*.domain.com`  this will allow others to know that `jack.domain.com` leads to a valid location.

Once that is done, your `.htaccess` will need to know how to handle a `*.domain.com` requests. More information on this can be found at [htaccess subdomain redirect rules](http://blog.gwebtools.com/apache-htaccess-subdomain-redirect-rules/).

The gist of it is that someone goes to `jack.domain.com` your server sees this and then says, Ok we are passing `jack` as part of the query string so each page can see we are working under `jack`. Then in your scripts you would just use that information to pull it up and display the data for `jack`.

There are many different ways this can be setup, so it is hard to say how to tailor to your needs. But hopefully that is enough information to get you started. Just remember, if you are testing on localhost, localhost `HOST` file does not allow wildcard DNS names, so for testing you have to manually add each subdomain to that host file for testing.

Comment: But will i be able to customize like the main site? Because I have clients who want customizations... like let' say all users have access to photo sharing, then one client such as jack may say i want option to share and allow comments, create and activate that for me...

Comment: As long as your site is setup to do such requests, yes. You can say `jack` has access to `photos` but `bill` did not want access to `photos` so that shows a "not implemented" page. So when they goto jack.domain.com/photos it shows his photo page, but bill.domain.com shows some form an error.  A great example of this setup in action is Wordpress MU (multi-user).