# Does WordPress have the functionality to create a new subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I simply need to know if there is any built in functionality or a plugin that can create a new subdomain for "MyDomain.com" from within the WordPress setup. I've heard from a couple dev friends of mine that it's possible, but nobody has been able to point me in the right direction.

Personally, I don't think it's possible. Or safe. But maybe somebody on SO can shed some light on it for me. Have any of you heard of such a thing?

Others have danced around my question without answering it. The closest I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660177/when-you-auto-create-subdomains-on-user-signup-does-it-create-a-new-website-or-g).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domains and subdomains are handled on the domain name record. Is it technically possible to handle this in WordPress? Well I guess technically it's possible in the same way that it's technically possible to program a computer to cook your breakfast or it's technically possible to build a SQL Server based version of WordPress.... I mean, technically I guess it's possible. But it's kind of pointless. I'd be surprised if anyone ever bothered.

That being said, there is one important exception to this. That concerns MutliSite WordPress installs with the MU Domain Mapping plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/).

In multisite with domain mapping, with a few tweaks to your domain name record, such as a * in your CNAME, you can define new CNAME's for different blogs within a WordPress network. You can learn more about MultiSite here http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network and, again, the MU plugin here http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/